# ?? null coalesce for Chrome V79

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

We use embedded chrome in our application which is tied to V79.

However the application loads GoogleMaps API using

```HTML
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    defer></script>
```

This is posing a challenge with new operators like ?? coalesce of ES not supported with the version of the browser.
Can there be a simple approach at all

1. JavaScript does not support for me to provide a global operator, I believe
2. Search/replace for evaluations would be error prone
3. Parsing and rewriting whole JS loaded would be complex

```HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Display Google Maps API Version</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        // Add your map here.
        console.log('Google Maps API version: ' + google.maps.version);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    defer></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why not request a version of the dependency that is compatible? See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions